# Find the signature of quadratic form : $\left(x^2+y^2+z^2\right)-4\left(xy+xz+yz\right)$

Tags: linear-algebra, quadratic-forms

If anyone can help I would like to know what is the signature of the following quadratic form :

> > $$f(x,y,z) = \left(3x^2+4y^2+z^2\right)-9\left(5xy+3xz+yz\right)$$

A few steps would be a lot appreciated thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint**

$$f(x,y,z)=\begin{pmatrix}x&y&z\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}1&-2&-2\\-2&1&-2\\-2&-2&1\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}x\\y\\z\end{pmatrix}.$$

Then try to diagonalize the matrix (at least, finding the eigenvalue is enough).

Comment: Hello Alright I've done it I've found $\lambda_1 = 3 $ mulitplicity of 2 , and $\lambda_2 = -3 $ But how does it help with the signature ..

Comment: Sorry never mind I can read the signature in the diagonal matrix which contains the eigenvalues

Comment: Sorry but how did you find the following matrix , using gauss algorithm ?

Comment: Not at all. I guessed it. But in more complicated cases, you can also solve the equation $$(x\ y\ z)\begin{pmatrix}a&b&c\\b&d&e\\c&e&f\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}x\\y\\z\end{pmatrix}=x^2+y^2+z^2-4(xy+yz+xz).$$ @mugiwara

Comment: @mugiwara The matrix is half the Hessian of $f$, i.e. $\nabla^2f(x)/2$.

Comment: @ViktorioElHakim: very good remark !  (I didn't realized that, but it definitely make sense)